# How to count row in mysql into two or more variables based on value?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I want to count users which are upgraded or standard into **users['upgraded']** or **users['standard']** variables, based on conditions in one query. I'm using mysql and PDO. "id" is primary key

Something like this:

```
$user[upgraded] =

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
AS upgraded
WHERE (status1 > 0 OR status2 > 0 OR status3 > 0)
AND upgraded = 1
AND paused = 0
AND timestamp < $timestamp
ORDER BY id DESC
```

and

```
$user[standard] =

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
AS standard
WHERE (status1 > 0 OR status2 > 0 OR status3 > 0)
AND upgraded = 0
AND paused = 0
AND timestamp < $timestamp
ORDER BY id DESC
```

How would I get this in one query? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL boolean arithmetic, and *I believe this is the shortest possible answer*

```
SELECT  SUM(upgraded = 1) upgraded,
        SUM(upgraded = 0) downgraded
FROM    users
WHERE   (status1 > 0 OR status2 > 0 OR status3 > 0) AND 
        paused = 0  AND 
        timestamp < $timestamp
```

but if you want a more RDBMS friendly, use `CASE`

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN upgraded = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) upgraded,
        SUM(CASE WHEN upgraded = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) downgraded
FROM    users
WHERE   (status1 > 0 OR status2 > 0 OR status3 > 0) AND 
        paused = 0  AND 
        timestamp < $timestamp
```

Comment: @asprin no, `AS` is optional.

Comment: Really? Never knew that. Thanks

Comment: I've tried with SUM before, but I just couldn't get it working. Thank you J W.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(if(upgraded=1,1,0)) as upgraded,
       sum(if(upgraded=0,1,0) as standard from users
  where  etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Updated.